# HTML and Javascript: Remove a complete tag with dynamic content inside from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string that conains HTML. In this HTML I have a textbox with text inside:

```
<div class="aLotOfHTMLStuff"></div>
<textbox>This textbox must be terminated! Forever!</textbox>
<div class="andEvenMoreHTMLStuff"></div>
```

Now I want to remove the textbox from that string, including the text inside. The desired result:

```
<div class="aLotOfHTMLStuff"></div>
<div class="andEvenMoreHTMLStuff"></div>
```

How can I achieve it? The two main problems: It is a string and not part of the DOM and the content inside the textbox is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that will look for the opening and closing tags in the string and replace anything in between.

```js
const template = document.querySelector('#html')
const str = template.innerHTML

function removeTagFromString(name, str) {
  const reg = new RegExp('<' + name + '.*>.*<\/'+ name +'.*>\\n*', 'gm')
  return str.replace(reg, '')
}
console.log('before', str)
console.log('after', removeTagFromString('textbox', str))
```

```html
<template id="html">
<div class="aLotOfHTMLStuff"></div>
<textbox>This textbox must be terminated! Forever!</textbox>
<div class="andEvenMoreHTMLStuff"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: I'd like to know why my previous comment was removed... If you're afraid of TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ in ascii it gives : ["*do not use RegEx to parse XML markup*"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3702797)

Answer (score 1):

If it is text string not HTML, you can convert it to DOM:

```
var str = '<div class="aLotOfHTMLStuff"></div><textbox>This textbox must be terminated! Forever!</textbox><div class="andEvenMoreHTMLStuff"></div>';
var $dom = $('<div>' + str + '</div>');
```

Then remove element from DOM:

```
 $dom.find('textbox').remove();
```

If you need, can get string back:

```
console.log($dom.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var string = '<div class="aLotOfHTMLStuff"></div><textbox>This textbox must be terminated! Forever!</textbox><div class="andEvenMoreHTMLStuff"></div>';
if ( string.includes("<textbox>") ) {
 var start = string.indexOf("<textbox>");
  var stop = string.indexOf("</textbox>");
  string = string.replace(string.slice(start, stop+10), "");
}
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parseHTML to convert string to html,
like..

```
var str = '<div class="aLotOfHTMLStuff"></div><textbox>This textbox must be terminated! Forever!</textbox><div class="andEvenMoreHTMLStuff"></div>';
var a = $.parseHTML(str);
var newstr = ""; 
a.forEach(function(obj) {
    if ($(obj).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() != "textbox") {
        newstr += $(obj).prop("outerHTML")
    }
});
```

It's very simple and you can remove any tag in future by just replacing `"textbox"`

Answer (score -1):

> It is a string and not part of the DOM and the content inside the
>   textbox is dynamic.

So that html is in a js variable of type string? like this?:

```
var string = '<div class="aLotOfHTMLStuff"></div><textbox>This textbox must be terminated! Forever!</textbox><div class="andEvenMoreHTMLStuff"></div>';
```

So in that case you could use `.replace();` like this:

```
string = string.replace('<textbox>This textbox must be terminated! Forever!</textbox>', '');
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunetaly the text inside the textbox is dynamic. But I could write something to figure out the dynamic text, that could work with your solution.

Comment: Then pass the dynamic content with it something like this: `string = string.replace('<textbox>'+ dynamicContent +'</textbox>', '');`